# Why are acr.UserDialogs.Toast messages in my Xamarin.Forms app being truncated on devices?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, toast

We are using the acr.UserDialogs library to display Toasts on our Xamarin.Forms app. The messages are never more than a sentence long. In Android, the messages display fine, and the Toast will adjust size for the length of the message. Our QA tech realized that in iOS the messages were being truncated.

For example, the Toast

```
Title: "Connection Restored" 
Message: "Your connection has been reestablished"
```

is truncated to

```
Title: "Connection" 
Message: "Your connection has been"
```

when displayed on the device.

I tried changing the message to "Reconnected!" and all we see is "Reconnect"

The simulator on my Mac does not have this issue. I can see the whole message.

EDIT: I should point out that I we are using version 4.1.4 of the Acr.UserDialogs library and 2.2.0.45 for Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0):

Why? More than likely it's a bug with the library. But I assume you're also interested in a work-around.  Here's what's working for me: Just pad the string you want to display with spaces. I choose the same number of spaces as the number of characters in the original string.  So when the string is truncated in half, the remaining is what what you want to show in the first place (the part that's gets truncated is the one that contains spaces).

Let's say you want to display

```
"Connection"
```

you might get

```
"Conne"
```

So if you start with

```
"Connection          "
```

you would end up with

```
"Connection"
```

Silly, yes, but some work-arounds are.